# HTTP Response Sending JS Object Won't Work Using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, http

I've recently been creating a backend server in a C# console app for a program, implementing HTTPListiner and such. I am able to send responses back to the client when it is a normal string after it is converted to a byte array but for some reason when I try to return a javascript function, the client does not receive the information (checked with dev tools on chrome).

Code:

```
UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
user.accountname = Program.Response.tmpUser;
user.keyID = KeyTagID.GrabUserKeyTag(Program.Response.tmpUser);
user.friendsList = null;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

byteSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
resp.ContentLength64 = byteSend.Length;
resp.ContentType = "application/json";
resp.StatusCode = 200;
resp.SendChunked = true;
resp.OutputStream.WriteAsync(byteSend, 0, byteSend.Length);
resp.Close();
```

Although for some reason when I try something as simple as putting a "+" in front of the string before it gets converted int a byte array, then the JSON string is successfully sent to the client and it works out. Very confused.

Comment: `when I try to return a javascript function, the client does not receive the information` are you getting an error?

Comment: No error. I can print out what is returned in the console and it is a correct javascript string version of the object, for some reason sending it on its own through http isn't working for me though @SelimYıldız

Comment: @MikeyP can you add the response that you see in the console? Its confusing when you say JSON string is successfully sent to client if xxx, what happens in the other case?

Comment: {"accountname":"Mwp","keyID":24,"friendsList":null} gets printed out in the console. But when I try sending it to the client, no information gets sent over. Also I mentioned, when I just add any random character or value to the string before the object gets converted, then it succesfully sends to the client. For an example if I do byteSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("+" + json); it will work but unfortunantley will have an annoying + infront of it. @Yasser

Comment: Can you try `Write` instead of `WriteAsync` to test? Also I dont see any await for WriteAsync?

Comment: Using Write, 0 Bytes were sent over to the client-side (checked from the client page, the dev tools on chrome) @Yasser